# JQuery table sorter problem

Tags: jquery

I learned that by trying to use the tablesorter plug in from jquery the table needs to use the  < thead> and
< tbody> tags. I am using an html table, and I use the runat="server" attribute because I need to bind data to the table on the server side. but by using the runat= server attribute the code is rendered in a different way..instead of the view source looking like this which is what is in my markup view :

```
<table id="Table">
    <thead>
        <tr> <th>1st</th> <th>2nd</th> <th>3rd</th> </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>1st value</td><td>2nd value</td><td>3rd value</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1st value</td><td>2nd value</td><td>3rd value< /td></tr>
        <tr><td>1st value</td><td>2nd value</td><td>3rd value</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1st value</td><td>2nd value</td><td>3rd value</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

it looks like that but without the < thead> and < tbody> tags.. which will make the table sorter not work? can someone help me fix this? " .NET 3.5 sp1 is the version I am using"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should take a look here  -[Code Project Sortable Gridview using JQuery Tablesorter](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/SortableGridViewjQuery.aspx)

Essentially, you need to use the [UseAccessibleHeader property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.useaccessibleheader.aspx) of the Gridview so that a thead tag is outputted in the HTML output.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
if (this.gridView.Rows.Count > 0)
{
gridView.UseAccessibleHeader = true;
gridView.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
gridView.FooterRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableFooter;
}
}
```

if using a html table with the runat="server" attribute instead of asp.net server controls, it looks as though there isn't an easy way to prevent the thead tags from not rendering in the html output. You could use some JQuery to insert thead tags into the DOM on document ready-

```
    //in script tags after JQuery and JQuery tablesorter src declarations
    $(function() 
    {
        $('#test').prepend(
        $('<thead></thead>').append($('#test tr:first').remove()) 
        );

        $("#test").tablesorter();
            //your table options
    });


//your html and asp markup
<table id="test" runat="server">
<thead><tr><th>1</th><th>2</th><th>3</th></tr></thead>
<tbody>  
<tr><td>my data 1.1</td><td>this data 1.2</td><td>that data 1.3</td></tr>
<tr><td>this data 2.1</td><td>that data 2.2</td><td>my data 2.3</td></tr>
<tr><td>that data 3.1</td><td>my data 3.2</td><td>this data 3.3</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

outputs this, which works correctly with tablesorter-

```
<table id="test">
<thead>
<tr>
<th class="header">1</th>
<th class="header">2</th>
<th class="header headerSortDown">3</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>this data 1.1</td>
<td>that data 1.2</td>
<td>my data 1.3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>my data 2.1</td>
<td>this data 2.2</td>
<td>that data 2.3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>that data 3.1</td>
<td>my data 3.2</td>
<td>this data 3.3</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: is there a way to do this with still using the html table.. I have a lot of things already done using the html table. and I would hate to want to start over.

Comment: updated my answer to include solution for html table with runat="server" attribute

Comment: Russ cam could you explain this a little bit in detail..it works.but what Im trying to understand is what each part is doing?: (#'test).prepend($('<thead></thead>').append($('#test tr:first').remove())  and how did the tbody get inserted if you only mentioned thead

Comment: The tbody tag is outputted in the HTML from the ASP.NET page. 
The best way to understand the JQuery code is work from the inside out. So, $('#test tr:first').remove() removes the first tr tag (and wrapped contents) from table with ID="test."

Comment: Then, the first tr tag is appended to a newly created thead element, $('<thead></thead>'), that has been prepended (inserted before the content) of the element wrapped by the selector ('#test'), which in this case, is our test table.

Comment: I highly recommend the Manning JQuery in Action book to hone your JQuery skills - http://www.amazon.com/jQuery-Action-Bear-Bibeault/dp/1933988355/ref=pd_bbs_sr_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1229444358&sr=8-1
It is very well written and easy to follow

Comment: forgot to mention that $(function() { //code in here }); is just shorthand for $(document).ready(function() { //code in here });

Answer (score 0):

start with this...

```
print("<table class='turnMeIntoTableSort'><tr><td>heading1</td><td>heading2</td></tr><tr><td>content1</td><td>content2</td></tr><tr><td>content3</td><td>content4</td></tr></table>");
```

then do this:

```
print("$(document).ready(){
         $('table.turnMeIntoTableSort > tr:first').wrap('<thead></thead>');
         $('table.turnMeIntoTableSort > tr:gt(1)').wrapAll('<tbody></tbody>');

         //now draw the tablesorter
         $('table.turnMeIntoTableSort').tablesorter();
       }");
```

Comment: this looks like it might work.but looks can be deceiving..i will try tomorrow morning when I get by my data and I will give you an update