# jquery tablesorter usage without tbody and th block

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am very much interested to know how to use jquery tablesorter without `tbody` and `th` block, the reason behind this is I have many tables and css working which I generated from http://www.csstablegenerator.com/ site, in which only `tr` and `td` blocks only used

**This is working table with tbody block**  [Working default table style fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2mLRt/)

**But I want to sort table with only tr and td blocks**  [Expected Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bn9Cn/)

This is my test table which I want to sort

```
   <table border='1' id='test' >

    <!-- this is my header -->   
           <tr>
               <td>AlphaNumeric</td>
               <td>Numeric</td>
               <td>Animals</td>
               <td>Sites</td>
           </tr>


           <tr>
               <td>abc 123</td>
               <td>10</td>
               <td>Koala</td>
               <td>http://www.google.com</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>abc 1</td>
               <td>234</td>
               <td>Ox</td>
               <td>http://www.yahoo.com</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>abc 9</td>
               <td>10</td>
               <td>Girafee</td>
               <td>http://www.facebook.com</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>zyx 24</td>
               <td>767</td>
               <td>Bison</td>
               <td>http://www.whitehouse.gov/</td>
           </tr>

   </table>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery table sorter problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369762/jquery-table-sorter-problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you don't want to manually deal with the HTML of the table, so I would get jquery to do it for you:

```
var header = $("#test tr:first").html();
$("#test tr:first").remove();
$("#test").prepend('<thead>' + header + '</thead>');
$('#test').tablesorter();
```